# Fehlendes Komma nach "Angenommen"?

Tags: punctuation

> Angenommen es wird auf die Zeichenfolge „ABCDEB“ der reguläre Ausdruck
> A.*+B angewendet, so fände er keine Übereinstimmung.

Können wir annehmen, dass nach *angenommen* das Komma fehlt?

Comment: Ja, es kann angenommen werden, das nach "Angenommen" ein Komma fehlt.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich, das Befinden des Verbs auf der dritten Stelle im Satz ließ mich daran zweifeln. (Ich lerne Deutsch als Fremdsprache).

Comment: "Können wir annehmen, dass..." - da fehlt auch ein Komma.

Comment: -1 wegen »This question does not show any research effort«. Der Fragesteller hat sich keine Mühe gemacht, selbst eine Antwort zu finden. Falls er - entgegen dem Anschein - doch selbst nach einer Antwort gesucht haben sollte, hält er seine diesbezüglichen Bemühungen unglücklicherweise erfolgreich geheim.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Und da fehlt ein "s" in "dass".

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Da ist nun ein s zuviel und es fehlt nun ein n. ;) Man kann Kommentare übrigens dadurch korrigieren, dass man sie löscht und neu schreibt.

Comment: @PMF stimmt, dass ist mir in der Eile völlig entgangen. Sorry… kann es leider nicht mehr korrigieren

Comment: @Aditya, "das Befinden" ist im Deutschen fast ausschließlich im Sinn eines körperlichen und geistigen Zustands (~ ähnlich dem Englischen "condition") gemeint, z.B. "Wie ist Ihr Befinden?" = "Wie geht es Ihnen?", jedoch nicht im Sinn von "Position".

Comment: Danke @hanzlan. Es ist wichtig, sich dieser Nuancen bewusst zu sein.

Comment: Sich gegenüber einem Deutsch-Lehrner in ironische Spitzfindigkeiten zu vertiefen, mag vielleicht lustig sein, aber diese Kommentare und die, die sich auf "nicht ergatterte Punkte" beziehen, finde ich befremdlich. Geht es hier darum sinnvolle und unterstützende Antworten zu geben oder um möglichst viele Punkte? Liebe Grüße <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Angenommen" ist ein Partizip. Solche Partizipien oder, wenn sie um weitere Wörter erweitert sind, Partizipialgruppen können durch Komma abgetrennt werden, müssen es aber nicht.

Also kann man zwar[,] streng genommen[,] annehmen, dass hier ein Komma fehlt, liegt aber[,] die Regeln betrachtend[,] damit nicht notwendigerweise richtig.

https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/komma-partizip

Comment: +1. Diese Reaktion zeigt die Mühe, eine sachliche und detaillierte Antwort zu geben.

Comment: @Aditya, die Mühe, die in ihrer Frage fehlte. Und gerade weil sie dort fehlte, waren die wenigsten – ich eingeschlossen – willens, Mühe in eine sachliche und detaillierte Antwort zu stecken.

Comment: Das weiß ich zu schätzen, @Björn Friedrich. Aber lassen wir uns aus diesem Fall eine Lehre ziehen: Während wir dieser langen und teils mit negativen Emotionen geprägten Diskussion unsere Zeit widmeten, kam jemand, gab die Antwort und erntete 50 Punkte.

Comment: @Aditya, ... und provoziert damit weitere mangelhafte Fragen. Das ist ein Grund, weshalb ich gelegentlich Antworten auf offensichtliche Off-Topic-Fragen abwerte.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Ich stelle es mir für Sprachlerner schwierig vor, einen Ansatz für die Beantwortung zu finden, weil man ja erstmal rausfinden muss, was "Angenommen" hier eigentlich grammatisch ist. Nebensatz? Ellipse? Hauptsatz? Adverb? Wenn man das weiß, ist die Frage leicht zu googlen, aber ohne das? Die Frage könnte expliziter nach der grammatischen Struktur fragen, aber ein Nachweis eigenen Bemühens hätte die Frage für andere hier nicht nützlicher gemacht. Ich finde nicht, dass es an "details or clarity" fehlt, die Frage fragt klar nach dem Komma und implizit nach einer Regel dafür.